# How can I place something at the top of a queryset in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model `Post` with field `pinned_until = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)`. Let's say `pinned_until` has any value that is before the current time (timezone.now()), I want it to go at the top of the queryset, so it is first in the list of serialized response data.

How can I accomplish that? I know it has something to do with annotate, but I haven't been able to figure it out so far.

Comment: how about `order_by('-pinned_until','other fields')` . this way if 2 object have the same `pinned_until` they get ordered by next fields in line.